# How to fix dripping sound coming from toilets?

Tags: toilet

Two toilets doing the same thing: When solids or liquids are added to the bowls, a **dripping sound** can be heard.  Otherwise, they are silent.

There is *no* water leaking out of either toilet onto the floor.  Neither toilet flushes on its own.  I completely replaced all the innards of one of the toilets; it made no difference.

What is this dripping sound?  Do I need to fix it?  If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the sound is only heard *when material is added to the bowl*, you can disregard any involvement of the flushing mechanism. This must logically be the case, unless you omitted to mention that you also flushed the toilet afterwards, and/or that the liquid had entered the bowl from the water tank. If the latter is the case, the tank would make a gushing noise while it was refilling itself, and possibly some dripping sounds for a little while afterwards while the flushing mechanism settles down.

If the sound occurs when material is added to the bowl, but no associated flushing takes place, *the only possible source* of the dripping sound is the overflow from the S-bend when the liquid displaced from the bowl falls or runs down the sewer pipe. If there is no leakage from the toilet when you hear the sound, you can safely disregard it.

Comment: I hope you are right!