# Dripping Sound from inside toilet tank

Tags: leak, toilet

Ok so i've googled and have read

https://www.thisoldhouse.com/ask-toh/troubleshoot-dripping-toilet
[Why is there a continuous dripping sound coming from my toilet?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/69130/why-is-there-a-continuous-dripping-sound-coming-from-my-toilet?newreg=275bcdcf111340979423cb4da94618ec)

To stop the dripping sound I usually need to flush and 'jiggle' the flush handle.

Total plumbing noob and I'm also renting.

Going on vacation for a couple weeks soon.
My noob question
Is there any chance at all of flooding from a slow drip like this?

Will let landlord know but based on past experience expect a month or so before any maintenance is done.

Comment: If it stops when you jiggle the handle then I would suspect it's a poor seal between the flapper valve and its corresponding seat on the bottom of the cistern. Any leaking from here will just go into the bowl (and from there, into the sewer system), so while it's not great for your water bill, I would not expect it to cause a flood. See if cleaning the underside of the flapper helps at all.

Comment: Thanks! Was just wondering, since I'm a total idiot with plumbing, are toilet tanks designed so that they are normally 'flood proof'?
As you suggest I assume at worst I am just wasting water.
Just don't want to return after 2 weeks to a flooded apt

Comment: Pretty much, yes. There are 4 ways you could end up with a water outside the toilet/sewer: leaky tank-bowl fittings, leaky fill valve (at the tank), cracked porcelain, or leaky wax ring. The first three would all be apparent with water puddling on your bathroom floor. A leaky wax ring would be harder to detect because it's underneath the toilet, but it wouldn't likely have a constant dripping noise anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the flapper not making a good seal like was previously said here.  But I would recommend turning off the water main if possible when you leave for extended periods.  That's what I do.